# Translate message value to macro?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I need to translate a value to its corresponding message macro, such as 0x100 to WM_KEYDOWN.

Is there any exists open source implementation of this?

Comment: How many of these macros are there?  Can you just make a lookup table?

Comment: @KyleStrand: At run time, I need to output the name instead the value for some reason.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I know i need to make some kind of table, but i do want to write it by myself. So i am asking for an implementation.

Comment: The symbolic names aren't strings, though, so you're going to have to.

Comment: Just create a simple array with names in strings corresponding to every macro, like `char *names[] = {"NONE", "WM_KEYUP", ...}`

Comment: This should not be marked as duplicate. The answer on the linked solution is wrong. Check the comment there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your API vendor provides a way to do it, you're out of luck, and you're going to have to do it yourself.  The `#` stringification operator will help you type less:

```
struct macromap
{
    int macro,
    char *name;
};

#define MAP_ENTRY(macro)  { macro, #macro }

struct macromap map[] = 
{
  MAP_ENTRY(WM_KEYDOWN),
  MAP_ENTRY(WM_SOMETHINGELSE),
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Comment: good solution...+1, don't we all just *love* stringize preprocessor operator :)

Comment: Sometimes it gets the job done!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, probably i didn't understand you question correctly.

Every message is already defined as a DWORD macro, i assume you want this:

```
swith(value)
{
 case WM_KEYDOWN:
   do what you want
   break;
 case ...:
   ....
   break;
}
```